# GPS does not appear to be shutting down when view is closed

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, gps

i want to shutdown GPS after i close my view within a Google Map. But the arrow doesnt disappear!

Here is my Code from my View, called BlockMapView:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

if (self) {

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:g_lat
                                                            longitude:g_lng
                                                                 zoom:15];

    self.mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.bounds camera:camera];

    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    self.mapView.trafficEnabled = YES;
    self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    self.mapView.settings.compassButton = YES;



    [self addSubview:self.mapView];
```

And in the ViewController of the BlockMapView i want to shutdown the GPS with:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
self.blockMapView.mapView.myLocationEnabled = NO;
```

But the GPS is still running, and i´ve waited for 20 minutes.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because the arrow is still present in the menu bar doesn't mean the GPS radio is powered up. Apple even states this in the Privacy/LocationServices section of the Settings app in iOS: The presence of the arrow means that an app has 'recently used your location.'

Use the Energy Diagnostics template in Instruments while running the app to confirm if the GPS radio is still powered up.

Comment: Do you still have a reference to the view somewhere? Just setting `myLocationEnabled=NO` probably isn't sufficient. In the Apple Maps that just hides/shows the users location on the map, but it still uses the GPS to find their location. Make sure there aren't any strong references to GMSMapView or the BlockView that contains it. Once they're all nil'd the map should be deallocated. Also, are you sure the GPS is activated (solid blue)? A gray bar means it is powered off, that confused me the first time I used it.

Comment: I´ve made some more Tests with the Energy Diagnostic template, and regognize some very strange Things, i activated the flight mode and the template shows a solid red bar for wifi and GPS (and red means activated).....Also i found out that when i take my device off from Xcode and shut down WLAN the gray GPS arrow dissapears correctly....i´m confused...

Comment: In Airplane Mode the phone can still have WiFi & GPS activated, if you allow it. It sounds like you might have encountered a bug/conflict with the Google Map SDK, I'd recommend posting the details on their forum. Have you tried the Apple Maps SDK, just to rule out something in your code vs. theirs?

Comment: Yes it seems to be a bug, i will report it, thanks for your help :)